# Error when adding "dnf copr enable @spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.10-client"

Tags: spacewalk

I am getting this error when trying to install spacewalk client on one of the Fedora 31 server.

```
# dnf copr enable @spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.10-client
Enabling a Copr repository. Please note that this repository is not part of the main distribution, and quality may vary.

The Fedora Project does not exercise any power over the contents of this repository beyond the rules outlined in the Copr FAQ at <https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#what-i-can-build-in-copr>, and packages are not held to any quality or security level. 
Please do not file bug reports about these packages in Fedora Bugzilla. In case of problems, contact the owner of this repository.

Do you really want to enable copr.fedorainfracloud.org/@spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.10-client? [y/N]: y
Error: This repository does not have any builds yet so you cannot enable it now.
```

I remember able to install it on server A but when try same on server B getting this error. I am not sure whats different.

```
Server A $ cat /etc/os-release .
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="31 (Server Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=31
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f31"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 31 (Server Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:31"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=31
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=31
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy"
VARIANT="Server Edition"
VARIANT_ID=server

Server B# cat /etc/os-release
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="31 (Server Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=31
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f31"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 31 (Server Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:31"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=31
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=31
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy"
VARIANT="Server Edition"
VARIANT_ID=server
```

Here is the one of the system where I was able to installed earlier:

```
# rhn_register --version
 rhn_register (Spacewalk Client Tools) 2.10.10-1.fc31
 Copyright (C) 1999--2014 Red Hat, Inc.
 Licensed under the terms of the GPLv2.

# cat /etc/redhat-release
 Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because this project does not provide builds for Fedora 31. See https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/g/spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.10-client/

You can try your luck enforcing a platform with

```
dnf copr enable @spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.10-client epel-8-x86_64
```

which will succeed in enabling the repo. But whether RHEL8 packages will work on Fedora 31 is hard to say.

Comment: so, that means they did provide fedora build at some point but then removed it?

Comment: Is there binary available that I can just install via rpm install?

Comment: It didn't work but it should have because RHEL 8 is based of Fedora 28..

Comment: Spacewalk project is not maintained anymore. Yeah, they provided Fedora builds, but as these version of Fedoras has been EOLed, they have been removed from Copr.

Comment: any way to find binaries or a way to copy from a system it's working?